# Devise_invitable app/views/devise/invitation.html.erb 'registration' fields RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I'm sure there are people out there who have done this.  I started down it, but I made my app crash a few times, so I figured I'd just ask out there rather than continue driving my webapp in to oblivion.  I'm using devise_invitable gem.  It sends a link to invited users, they click the link, and they're directed to this view @ app/views/devise/invitation.html.erb:

```
<h2><%= t 'devise.invitations.edit.header' %></h2>

<%= simple_form_for resource, as: resource_name, url: invitation_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put } do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
<%= f.hidden_field :invitation_token %>

<%= f.input :password %>
<%= f.input :password_confirmation %>

<%= f.button :submit, t("devise.invitations.edit.submit_button") %>
<% end %>
```

I want to add some fields, for example

```
<%= f.input :firstname %>
```

When I do that, though, it *does* appear in the view, though it's not saving to the User model.  So, I figured I needed to modify the controller.  That's where I get confused, I think because I'm trying to flop back and forth between the devise and devise_invitable readme's.  I'm using devise 3.5.6 and devise_invitable 1.5.5.  I tried adding the above input to the form, and changing the applicaiton controller to include

```
 before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

 protected

 def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :firstname
 end
```

but that still doesn't save to my user model.  Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are permitting `params` that pass on to  devise `RegistrationsController` `create` action. You can see it in definition, below params sanitizer is for `:sign_up`
`devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :firstname`

In your case it must be `:accept_invitation`, Since you are using devise_invitable and form submit url is invitation_path which will submit to `Devise::InvitationsController#update`

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:accept_invitation) do |u|
    u.permit(:firstname)
end
```

More details [here](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#strong-parameters)

Comment: Oh, damn.  That was easy.  If I only would have followed through and clicked that strong parameters link before.  Thanks @rahul-singh